# Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check

Tags: firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I'm setting firebase on my project and when I add inappmessaging-display lib this error appears:

> Dependency resolved to an incompatible version:
> Dependency(fromArtifactVersion=ArtifactVersion(groupId=com.google.firebase,
> artifactId=firebase-messaging, version=17.3.2),
> toArtifact=Artifact(groupId=com.google.firebase,
> artifactId=firebase-iid), toArtifactVersionString=[17.0.2]) FAILURE:
> Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during
>   up-to-date check.  In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services
>   library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g.
>   "[17.0.   2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior
>   exhibited by the library will be unknown.
>   Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[17.0.2], but fire   base-iid version was 17.0.3.
>   The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art   ifact
>   with the issue.   -- Project 'app' depends onto
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@17.0.3   -- Project 'app' depends
>   onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.3.2   -- Project 'app'
>   depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ads@17.1.2   -- Project
>   'app' depends onto
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@17.0.4   --
>   Project 'app' depends onto
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@16.0.6   -- Project 'app'
>   depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@16.2.4   --
>   Project 'app' depends onto
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@17.0.4   -- Project 'app'
>   depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.6   -- Project
>   'app' depends onto
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl@17.0.4   --
>   Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@16.1.3
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crash@16.2.1   -- Project 'app' depends
>   onto com.google.firebase:firebase-abt@16.0.1   -- Project 'app'
>   depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@16.2.3   -- Project
>   'app' depends onto
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@16.0.4
>   For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep   endency
>   paths to the artifact. This error message came from the
>   google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your build.gradle
>   file.

```
project file

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.16'
}
ext {
    support_library_version = '28.0.0' //use the version of choice
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


app gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.pocapp"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_library_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_library_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Play services dependencies
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1')

    //General google dependencies
    implementation('com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0')
    implementation('com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2')

    //Firebase dependencies
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.3')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:17.0.4')
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4')

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I already updated all libs to latest versions.

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1155#issuecomment-395944013 solved it for me. As silly as it sounds, adding com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true at the end of my build.gradle fixed this. It's a work around for a bug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was on firebase libs versions, Just update every lib to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue,
At finally got a Solution.
Please remove Cordova-plugin-firebase and

Use the latest major releases just by running: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib

Simply follow the following link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib

Answer (score -1):

Check your internet connection.
If you are connected,try to use a proxy server (using hotspot shield,PSiphone, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

`cd android
./gradlew clean`
try this

Comment: Do you also have an explanation what that does?

Comment: Usually, this just delete the build directory, on the next build it will be recreated.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. In my case I'm using `ionic4` `Angular`